# How do I sync my standalone(local) postgres database to cloud (AWS RDS)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-migration

I have a local postgres database for my application. Everyday new data is added to the DB. I want to set up a job that will sync my local data to an RDS instance everyday at a particular time.

I know running `pg_dump` in local and `pg_restore` in the AWS instance or image but that dumps the entire data and imports all the data to RDS. While I want only the updated data to be uploaded everyday and not the part that I've already uploaded.

What should I use?

Comment: this belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: What about replication?

Comment: I found my answer in AWS docs.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html

Comment: @NikhilLaddha, can the CDC task live forever?  Did your use case require the replication to go on forever?